# Hide TableView when load it and active it when the result has found by typing in Search Bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In iPhone or iPod, when we go to the page search we see only the search bar but if we type to find one application it will show the result with table view so my question is how we can do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UISearchDisplayController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the answer for this question. This controllers comes built-in `UISearchBar`.

Also, this controller itself will manage hiding and unhiding (or making transparent)  the tableview whenever you search in searchbar.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848) is the sample code provided by Apple which will help you.

I hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Initially make table hidden and search anything, reload tableview and than show table .

Answer (score 0):

it is used UIsearchDisplayController controller which is contain search bar and table view when search bar found record it shows in tableview if you want example then check the link here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html